# error: unable to create symlink, fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'

Tags: git, version-control, git-stash

I am trying to hard reset with `git reset origin/dev --hard`,

```
...
error: unable to create symlink Codes/Pods/Headers/Public/libPhoneNumber-iOS/NBPhoneNumberDefines.h: No such file or directory
error: unable to create symlink Codes/Pods/Headers/Public/libPhoneNumber-iOS/NBPhoneNumberDesc.h: No such file or directory
error: unable to create symlink Codes/Pods/Headers/Public/libPhoneNumber-iOS/NBPhoneNumberUtil.h: No such file or directory
error: unable to create symlink Codes/Pods/Headers/Public/libPhoneNumber-iOS/NBRegExMatcher.h: No such file or directory
error: unable to create symlink Codes/Pods/Headers/Public/libPhoneNumber-iOS/NBRegularExpressionCache.h: No such file or directory
error: unable to create symlink Codes/Pods/Headers/Public/libPhoneNumber-iOS/NSArray+NBAdditions.h: No such file or directory
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/dev'.
```

Then I saw some unstaged files and I am getting below error when I try to run `git stash` after `git add .`,

```
...
error: unable to create symlink Codes/Pods/Headers/Public/libPhoneNumber-iOS/NBPhoneNumberDefines.h: No such file or directory
error: unable to create symlink Codes/Pods/Headers/Public/libPhoneNumber-iOS/NBPhoneNumberDesc.h: No such file or directory
error: unable to create symlink Codes/Pods/Headers/Public/libPhoneNumber-iOS/NBPhoneNumberUtil.h: No such file or directory
error: unable to create symlink Codes/Pods/Headers/Public/libPhoneNumber-iOS/NBRegExMatcher.h: No such file or directory
error: unable to create symlink Codes/Pods/Headers/Public/libPhoneNumber-iOS/NBRegularExpressionCache.h: No such file or directory
error: unable to create symlink Codes/Pods/Headers/Public/libPhoneNumber-iOS/NSArray+NBAdditions.h: No such file or directory
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.
```

**What can be the cause and how to resolve it?**

Comment: I have also tried with `git gc` and then `git reset` but no luck.

Comment: Does it all happen in the same directory `Codes/Pods/Headers/Public/libPhoneNumber-iOS/` ? check your access rights on this folder : `ls -ld [folder]` and the files in this folder : `ls -l [folder]`

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x 1 CORP+hissain` i got that output @LeGEC

Comment: I'm not familiar with MacOS : is `CORP+hissain` your regular username ? or the owner you see when looking at a file that you created with your account ?

Comment: @LeGEC yes its me. I can change codes and commit as well that means I have write permission already.

Comment: Ok, then you have write access to the *folder* wheck the content of the folder to see if something could prevent git to create a symlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by below command,

```
git config --global core.symlinks false
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem: `unable to create symlink tests/generated/base: File name too long
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision`