# Duplicate and uncommitted Firebase header files for an iOS app in Xcode stored in iCloud

Tags: swift, xcode, github, icloud, icloud-drive

**TLDR: How is everyone's experience on storing your Xcode apps on both iCloud and GitHub?**

I have 2 Macs (15" MacBook Pro 2016 and M1 Mac Mini) and I have my Swift codes stored in my GitHub and in my iCloud because I want my changes on my MB Pro to also appear on my M1 Mac Mini. Also I dont have both Macs's Xcode app open at the same time to make it easier on iCloud. Everything was working fine because M1 Mini was booted via a TimeMachine backup from my MacBook Pro, until I had to reformat my Mac Mini because it thinks it is a MacBook Pro so some apps were not working.

Except for Notability, I was able to fix most apps issues by redownloading them, however, there were still instance were my Mac Mini would ask me to login via finger print to authenticate. Since I had most of my notes on my Notability, and I couldn't take not being able to use Notability anymore due to college classes purposes. So I reformatted my M1 Mini and did the entire environment setup.

**Now the issue/question**
I opened Xcode one of the app I am working on my Mac Mini from iCloud Drive which surprisingly code still runs. However, I see these 6 Firebase header files on my unstaged files, while on my MacBook Pro there are no unstaged files. Anyone knows what is going on? Should I just ignore it?

I tried git force resetting my local branch

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/samuel/feature1
```

but I get the following error.

```
error: unable to read sha1 file of Multiverse/Pods/Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h (07ac6eb193d61bc7bf93a47fda7e949fc6d12cd7)
error: unable to read sha1 file of Multiverse/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop/FIRCoreDiagnosticsData.h (ce646ecf1d2e4f0e748e81842f81604064ae3f5c)
error: unable to read sha1 file of Multiverse/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop/FIRCoreDiagnosticsInterop.h (07d83d70f41da4aaa329489cc8528ac5709ee382)
error: unable to read sha1 file of Multiverse/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h (07ac6eb193d61bc7bf93a47fda7e949fc6d12cd7)
error: unable to read sha1 file of Multiverse/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop/FIRCoreDiagnosticsData.h (ce646ecf1d2e4f0e748e81842f81604064ae3f5c)
error: unable to read sha1 file of Multiverse/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop/FIRCoreDiagnosticsInterop.h (07d83d70f41da4aaa329489cc8528ac5709ee382)
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/samuel/feature1'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by below command,

```objectivec
git config core.symlinks false
```

see more please click this link:[error: unable to create symlink, fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63374527/error-unable-to-create-symlink-fatal-could-not-reset-index-file-to-revision)