# Git: Clone succeeded but checkout failed

Tags: git, gitlab, git-clone

When pulling the repo from gitlab i get the following error:
`warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed. You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status' and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'`

Running the command:
 `git restore --source=HEAD :/`
produces:
`-global is not a valid attribute name: .gitattributes:2 error: unable to create file [filename_redacted]: Filename too long`

.gitattributes line 2 looks like this:
`$ git config --global core.autocrlf true`

When I edit it out of the .gitattributes, it auto-reappears.
When I issue `git status` I'm getting all the files from the repo as edited. Standard commands as `git reset` don't do any good either.
Is there anything I can do with this repo to make it work properly?
Should I ask the repo owner/someone who has it pulled and working to fix it before pulling it again? How?

Comment: Found this post that may be related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041752/github-clone-succeeded-but-checkout-failed

Comment: I've seen this post. I issued the command to fix long filenames but I'm still getting the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I ask what OS are you using? If you have windows looks like it doesn't let you pass some filename formats:

- https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/208
- https://github.com/t-b/git-pre-commit-hook-windows-filenames

Found another post using `git config --global core.symlinks false` for a work around, hope it can work:
[Why is clone succeeded, but checkout failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70540664/why-is-clone-succeeded-but-checkout-failed)

Comment: I use windows. I tried the solution with git hooks and I'm still getting the error: `-global is not a valid attribute name: .gitattributes:2`

Comment: Found another post using ```git config --global core.symlinks false``` for a work around, hope it can work:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70540664/why-is-clone-succeeded-but-checkout-failed

Comment: It worked! I can use the repo now

Comment: Glad it can help! Yay!